# There is a common usage of interfaces in Java – to tell an object has a specific use or characteristic

Tags: java

There is a common usage of interfaces in Java – to tell an object has a specific use or characteristic. Let's give a real-world example. You are trying to survive in the woods. You find different objects and put them in your backpack for later use. When you rest you go through the found objects and eat the ones that are edible.

First, let's define an interface called FoundObject with no methods at all. Those are all the objects we found in the woods:

```
  interface FoundObject { }
```

Now we define a second interface called Edible. We will use it just to denote if the object is edible or not.

```
  interface Edible { 
    public void eat(); 
  }
```

We create the interface FoundObject with the sole purpose to denote the objects of specific type, so we can put them in the same array. We create the Edible interface to mark which objects can be eaten.

Now, we will define the objects we find in the woods – fruit and stones. When we create the two objects (fruit and stone) we put implements FoundObject in the class declaration for all of them, and the ones we can eat also implement the Edible interface. We will first write the Fruit class and will write the Stone class in the subsequent question. The Fruit class contains the following:

- A private instance variable named name of type String.
- A constructor method which sets up the instance variable
- A toString() method which returns the name of the fruit
- A overridden eat() method which prints a description as shown below.
  For example:

**Test**

```
Fruit orange = new Fruit("Orange");
orange.eat();

Result:
     Yummy! you ate an Orange
FoundObject orange = new Fruit("Orange");
System.out.println(orange);

Result:
   Orange
```

Here is the code I attempted, Please have a look.

```
import java.awt.Point;
abstract class Shape implements Comparable<Shape> {
   protected Point p; // top-left corner

   public Shape() {
       p = new Point();
   }

   public Shape(int x, int y) {
       p = new Point(x, y);
   }

   public String toString() {
       return String.format("%d", perimeter());
   }

   public abstract int perimeter();

   public int compareTo(Shape other) {
       return this.perimeter() - other.perimeter();
   }
}

class Circle extends Shape {
   private int radius;

   public Circle() {
   }

   public Circle(int x, int y, int r) {
       super(x, y);
       radius = r;
   }

   public int perimeter() {
       return (int) (Math.PI * 2 * radius);
   }
}

class Rectangle extends Shape {
   private int width, height;

   public Rectangle() {
   }

   public Rectangle(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
       super(x, y);
       width = w;
       height = h;
   }

   public int perimeter() {
       return (width + height) * 2;
   }
}
```

And the error message, please help me to change it. Many thanks~

```
Syntax Error(s)
__Tester__.java:26: error: error while writing Circle: Circle.class (Permission denied)
class Circle extends Shape {
^
1 error
```

Comment: You're compiling in a folder you don't have access to (likely the JDK one?). Move to another folder.

Comment: The error you are getting has nothing to do with the whole story about interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

That's because of the access of the class `Circle` which is `default` but the constructors and inner parts are `public`. Change the class level to `public`. The same to `Rectangle`.